# How can I define this OR type on Typescript to avoid that errors?

Tags: typescript

I have problems with types...There are some errors using this OR typing. I need to give to **elements** prop a different type depending of **type** prop, how I could do that? Thanks.

Code:

```
      interface LayoutProps {
        type: LayoutPropsType;
        elements: OneElementLayoutProps | TwoElementsLayoutProps;
      }
      interface OneElementLayoutProps {
        component: React.ReactElement;
      }
      interface TwoElementsLayoutProps {
        leftcomponent: React.ReactElement;
        rightcomponent: React.ReactElement;
      }
      ...
      {layout.type === LayoutPropsType.one && (
        <OneElementLayout
          component={layout.elements.component} // Error. Don't exists on TwoElementsLayoutProps
        ></OneElementLayout>
      )}
      {layout.type === LayoutPropsType.two && (
        <TwoElementsLayout
          leftComponent={layout.elements.leftComponent} // Error. Don't exists on OneElementLayoutProps
          rightComponent={layout.elements.rightComponent} // Error. Don't exists on OneElementLayoutProps
        ></TwoElementsLayout>
      )}
      ...
```

Comment: That is not an "or" type, it's a [type union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). This means you'll have to account for BOTH types whenever you want to access it.

Comment: There are a few things wrong here. First, TypeScript only exists at compile time, so you could not do runtime type checking. Second, as Rawley Fowler said, the pipe symbol (|) refers to a union, which accepts either the type on the right side of the `|` or the one on the left.